# How to Add Increment of +1 to every instance of a repeated username

Tags: linux, shell, unix

```
echo "Enter your First Name: "; read first
echo "Enter your Last Name: "; read last
user=${first:0:1}${last:0:4}
echo "Your Username is: " $user
echo $user":"$first":"$last>> Print.txt
```

So far i can store the first/last name of a user into a file and use that information to create then a unique username based off the information provided that is also stored in the file. But realizing that many people can have the same username how would I make it search through the print.txt file to see if there are multiple of the same username and then add the correct increment to the username based on that. I am thinking i will need a while loop and grep -q but i have at this for awhile and cant figure it out.

Example to visually show what i'd like to achieve

```
 first name: daniel
 last name: nash
 user name will be DNASH

 first name: donna
 last name: nash
 user name will be DNASH1

 first name: donald
 last name: nash
 user name will be DNASH2
```

Comment: `if grep -q "^$user:" Print.txt` will tell you if the username is already in the file. Do that in a loop where you keep appending the next number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a while loop, you could use the "-c" option of grep:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ ! -f Print.txt ] && touch Print.txt 
read -p "Enter your First Name: " _FIRST
read -p "Enter your Last Name: " _LAST
_USER=${_FIRST:0:1}${_LAST:0:4}
_COUNT=`grep -c "${_USER}" Print.txt`
if [ ${_COUNT} -gt 0 ] ; then
    _USER="${_USER}${_COUNT}"
fi
echo "Your Username is: ${_USER}"
echo "${_USER}:${_FIRST}:${_LAST}" >> Print.txt
```

Does that accomplish what you had in mind?

Comment: What does -gt option for the 'if' statement do? And yes it works great thankyou.

Comment: "-gt" is a numerical comparison operator that means "greater than".  The others are "-eq" (equal), "-ne" (not equal), "-lt" (less than), "-le" (less than or equal), and "-ge" (greater than or equal).  You can get more information from the "CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS" section of the "sh" man page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
n=""
while grep -qFx "${user}$n" <(cut -d: -f1 Print.txt); do 
    ((n++))
done
user="$user$n"
echo "user name will be $user"
```